# can't call persist if entity manager in entity listener

Tags: jpa, jboss, ejb

I need persist a new entity object in entity listener, 
but it only working fine at first call.

please see code as below:

```
    public class SomeListener{
         @PreUpdate
         public void preUpdate(SomeEntity o){
             EntityManager em= EntityManagerUtils.getEntityManager();
             em.persist(new OtherObj());
         }
    }
    public class EntityManagerUtils {
        protected static EntityManager getEntityManager() throws Exception {
            Object sb = new InitialContext().lookup(JNDI_EntityLisenterSB);
            Method method = sb.getClass().getMethod("getEntityManager");
            return (EntityManager) method.invoke(sb);
    }}
```

**get below error log after second call:**

```
ARJUNA012125: TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion - failed for SynchronizationImple< 0:ffffac19b619:7c4a5bbb:56cfb972:19e, org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.JTASynchronizationListener@7bece143 >: java.lang.NullPointerException

...

javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back

...

Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA016053: Could not commit transaction.
```

**but the new object already saved to DB**

```
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1177)

at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:126)
at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:75)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:92) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
... 94 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.updateObjectForWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:1005)
```

**any one can help?  thanks a lot.**

**working environment**

- jboss eap6.2
- oracle11g
- eclipselink 2.4.1

Comment: why your getEntityManager() method is protected ?

Comment: I assume you're within an application managed persistence context, am I right?

Comment: hi aribeiro,
yes, i'm using JTA in jobss , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Once the entity is committed, that entity becomes detached. A commit gets executed by the first call to `persist()`, causing your entity to get detached. What you can do is to begin the transaction again before calling another `persist()`.

```
getTransaction().begin();
```

Comment: thanks Bernard,
**I'm using JTA transaction type, so cannot use getTranscation().begin() .**

Actually here only once committed.
 i update details entity code and ejb code on my question, thanks

Comment: Oh, well then I think you can just annotate your `preUpdate()` method with `@javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute(javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)`

Comment: thanks Bernard,<br/>
the entitylistener class is not a EJB, so it that annotate not working at here, I changed code as bolew and the save new object work now

>`SomListener extends DescriptorEventAdapter`<br/>
>`preUpdate(DescriptorEvent event)`<br/>
thank.